# aiohttp websocket and redis pub/sub

Tags: websocket, publish-subscribe, aiohttp

i created a simple websocket server using aiohttp . my server reads message from redis pub/sub and sends it to client .
this is my websocket code:

```
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import web
import aioredis


router = web.RouteTableDef()

@router.get("/ws")
async def websocket_handler(request):

    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)
    sub = request.config_dict["REDIS"]
    ch, *_ = await sub.subscribe('hi')

    async for msg in ch.iter(encoding='utf-8'):
        await ws.send_str('{}: {}'.format(ch.name, msg))

async def init_redis(app):
    redis_pool = await aioredis.create_redis_pool('redis://localhost')
    app["REDIS"] = redis_pool
    yield
    redis_pool.close()
    await redis_pool.wait_closed()



async def init_app():
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes(router)
    app.cleanup_ctx.append(init_redis)
    return app


web.run_app(init_app())
```

my first client can connect to server and receive messages but when i create another client to connect to this endpoint it receive no messages !
what is the problem ? how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call create_redis for each client and publish the message to the channel. Otherwise, only the first client will receive the subscribed message.
So, you can edit your code as follows.

```py
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import web
import aioredis
import asyncio

router = web.RouteTableDef()


async def reader(ws, ch):
    while (await ch.wait_message()):
        await ws.send_str('{}: {}'.format(ch.name, msg))


@router.get("/ws")
async def websocket_handler(request):
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)
    sub = await aioredis.create_redis_pool('redis://localhost')
    pub = await aioredis.create_redis_pool('redis://localhost')
    
    ch, *_ = await sub.subscribe('hi')

    asyncio.ensure_future(reader(ws, ch))
    async for msg in ws:
        await pub.publish('hi', msg)

    sub.close()
    pub.close()


async def init_app():
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes(router)
    return app


web.run_app(init_app())
```

Please note there may be minor syntax error (e.g. format of the message), but this is the structure that you should follow as it worked for me. I got it to work with my application.